# Cassandra: backup entire keyspace

Tags: cassandra, backup

I was just wondering what would be the best way to backup an entire keyspace in Cassandra... what do you think?

Previously i just copied the data folder into my backup hard drive, but then i had problems to restore the database after updating.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way is by doing snapshots (`nodetool snapshot`). You can learn a lot about how that works and how best to use it in this [Datastax documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsSnapShot.html) (disclaimer: I work for Datastax).

You'll want to make sure you have JNA enabled (some relevant instructions can be found on [this page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installJnaRHEL.html)). If you do, snapshots are *extremely* fast; they're just hard links to existing sstables. No copying needs to be done. You can combine snapshots with other backup tools (or just rsync, cp, etc) if you want to keep track of your backups in a particular way.

Comment: This seems like a terrible design. I'm forced to find the current version of the table tablename-asdfasfsadfaf >> change to that directory >> copy the snapshot files out.. and then do this like 50 times because I have to do it once for each table. There should be a way to snapshot all the files to one output directory or a single backup file. Best you can do is write some script to pull out all the files.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites, it is rather kludgey, but not too difficult to deal with.  You can use the snapshot name to either move or copy the data to wherever you want to store it.  If you choose a name when creating a snapshot that makes it easier.  If you don't you can use the `nodetool listsnapshots` command to get the name (that feature was introduced in cassandra 2.1).

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a simple python tool to automate cluster snapshots and backups and store them on S3.

https://github.com/tbarbugli/cassandra_snapshotter is the github page, there you can also find the documentation

Comment: Any chance you also wrote a restore tool?

Answer (score 6):

Beside reading the [Datastax documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/operations/backup_restore), I found the article ["incrementally backup up cassandra with amanda"](http://www.grulic.org.ar/~mdione/glob/posts/incrementally-backing-up-cassandra-with-amanda/) insightful. It's about how to use incremental backups and snapshots.

At the end, it recommends the following procedures:

1. Full backup

   - Remove old incremental files and symlinks.
   - `nodetool snapshot`
   - Symlink all the snapshot files to a backup directory
   - Backup that directory dereferencing symlinks.
   - `nodetool clearsnapshot` and remove symlinks.
2. Incremental backups (not to be confused with cassandra's builtin incremental backups):

   - `nodetool flush`
   - Symlink all incremental files into the backup directory.
   - Backup that directory dereferencing symlinks.
3. Restore

   - Restore the last full backup and all the incrementals.

Comment: When you say "Restore the last full backup" that's just re-stating the desired goal. But - how is this done? Is there a command? Is it as simple as copying the snapshot directories back into place?

Comment: @DonBranson It is also my understanding that the snapshot files need to be restored at their original location. The article mentions that they use a script to automate it (but without going into details): "Later, at restore time, the files are put in the backup directory, and with a script that takes the KS and CF from the file's name, they're 'dealed' to the right directories"

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to monitor the sstables that are being written, and incrementally backup those files.

Check out [tablesnap](https://github.com/synack/tablesnap), for example.

From the documentation:

Tablesnap is a script that uses inotify to monitor a directory for IN_MOVED_TO events and reacts to them by spawning a new thread to upload that file to Amazon S3, along with a JSON-formatted list of what other files were in the directory at the time of the copy.

When running a Cassandra cluster, this behavior can be quite useful as it allows for automated point-in-time backups of SSTables. Theoretically, tablesnap should work for any application where files are written to some temporary location, then moved into their final location once the data is written to disk. Tablesnap also makes the assumption that files are immutable once written.